# Question about sentence "The polls were ruled invalid"

Tags: passive-voice

I have a question about the following sentence.

"The polls were ruled invalid"

I know this is in the passive voice in that the subject polls is described as ruled.

But what what part of speech would "invalid" be?

I do not know if my question makes sense.

Comment: It's just an ordinary adjective. You wouldn't really say the polls are described as "ruled". Things like *paper* can be ruled, but for your context it means the polls are ***identified** [as being] invalid*.

Comment: Ok that make sense.

Comment: You might have found the cited text easier to understand if it had been more explicitly expressed as *The polls were ruled **to be** invalid*, but things like this are more appropriate on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), so I have voted for it to be migrated there.

Answer (score 1):

> The polls were ruled invalid.

The word *invalid* is an adjective here. I have a feeling that the question puzzling the Original Poster is actually what the grammatical function of the word *invalid* is. The answer is that it's a Predicative Complement. In this case it is describing the Subject of the sentence, *the polls*.

This sentence uses *RULE* in the passive voice. This verb is often used in the passive. This may make it more difficult to disentangle the grammatical relations in the sentence.

Comment: +1 But judges actively *rule* stuff all the time: "I'm going to rule that line of questioning out of order". And I'm going to rule that spelling of *polls* invalid. :)

Answer (score 0):

> "The polls were ruled invalid"

"Polls" is a noun. Words which describe nouns are called adjectives (red, big, old etc.). Hence in the above sentence, "invalid" is an adjective since it is describing "the polls". "ruled" is a verb as it represents an action (jump, sit, sleep, eat etc.). In this sentence an action is involved in turning "the polls" from a valid to an invalid state. This action is a "ruling" by, for example, a Supreme Court.

The following sentence is easier to understand perhaps:

> The walls (noun) were painted (verb) blue (adjective).